# wpf MVVM как изменить состояние view через viewmodel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Логика за изменение стиля кнопки, текста и еще кучи всего находится в View.cs в отдельных методах

Но эти методы необходимо вызвать из ViewModel.

Как организовать, чтобы из ViewModel можно было вызвать метод на изменение состояния View?

Comment: А у вас точно mvvm? Странно просто

Comment: View.cs - это `code behind` что ли?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите.

Если вам нужно поменять данные, вы просто меняете их в VM, и всё, View подхватывает их через привязку.

Если вам нужно поменять визуальное состояние, то вы делаете это не в VM, а во View.

Если вам нужно поменять визуальное состояние *в ответ на изменённые данные*, обычно делают так: вычисление визуального состояния делают через конвертер, и применяют его.

Пример: пусть вам нужно цвет фона менять в зависимости от значения. Для значений от 1 до 3 красный, от 4 до 10 жёлтый, больше зелёный. Делаем так:

Конвертер:

```
class ButtonColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var note = (int)value;
        var color = note <= 3 ? Colors.Red :
                    note <= 10 ? Colors.Yellow :
                    Colors.Green;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Height="150" Width="150">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ButtonColorConverter x:Key="ButtonColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding}"
                Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ButtonColorConverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]