# как в mvvm изменить цвет textbox. в свойстве set

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

как в mvvm изменить цвет textbox.  в свойстве set

```
    public string MinutesParamLongitudeInt
    {
        get { return minutesParamLongitudeInt; }
        set
        {
            try
            {

                minutesParamLongitudeInt = value;
                int intTemp; 

                if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intTemp))
                {
                    if (intTemp <= 60 && intTemp >= -60)
                    {
                        minutesParamLongitudeInt = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                } 
                else if (value == "-")
                {
                    minutesParamLongitudeInt = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    minutesParamLongitudeInt = null;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //textbox изменить цвет на красный 
                minutesParamLongitudeInt = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

В парадигме MVVM вью-модель не должна [ничего знать о конкретном представлении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597701/238074) (View), так как предполагается, что представления можно заменить без изменения кода вью-модели. Обмен данными между вью-моделью и представлением осуществляется через DataBinding.

---

А в вашем случае, проще вообще всё решить в разметке, использовав, например [Style.Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.style.triggers(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Control.Property" Value="value">
        <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите логику проверки в отдельный класс, наследующий [ValidationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=hL3Qp0zRBOc&ranSiteID=hL3Qp0zRBOc-R_bQ9iUO4o7Wl2IJy6Tw3A&tduid=%285892fb4039804223ca60d9e1d2008361%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28hL3Qp0zRBOc-R_bQ9iUO4o7Wl2IJy6Tw3A%29%28%29&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B).
Добавьте границы допустимого значения.

```
public class ValueRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int tempInt = 0;

        try
        {
            if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                tempInt = Int32.Parse((String)value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }


        if (tempInt > Min && tempInt < Max)
        {
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Введите число в диапазоне...");
        }
    }
}
```

Затем привяжите его к Вашему TextBox. Установите триггер на свойство `Validation.HasError`, именно оно будет указывать на правильность ввода.

```
<TextBox Margin="5">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                              NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ValueRule Min="-60" Max="60"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```